# Proper way to add attribute to custom Angular 2 component

Tags: angular, wai-aria

We have a custom input component in Angular 2. What is the proper way to add an attribute to our custom component? The gist of our input component is something like this.

*input-debounce.component.ts*

```
var template = `
  <input
    [type]="inputType"
    [placeholder]="placeholder">
`;

@Component({
  selector: "input-debounce"
  template: template
})

export class InputDebounceComponent {
  @Input() inputType: string = "text";
  @Input() placeholder: string = "";
}
```

What's the proper way to add an `aria-label` attribute to the custom component?

```
<input-debounce
  [inputType]="'number'"
  [placeholder]="'Enter Number'"
  [attr.aria-label]="'Age'">
</input-debounce>
```

or adding `[aria-label]="ariaLabel"` in `template`, and `@Input() ariaLabel = "";` in the class, then call it like `[ariaLabel]="'Age'"` when using the custom component?

When I did it the second way, Window's Narrator announce the aria label I put in, but the first way, it doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute), you could use `aria-label` on any html element, but it doesn't work like the way you used in the first attempt, `attr.aria-label` on a custom angular element (since the property `attr` is not defined on this custom element you created). In the second approach, you are basically passing the value for `aria-label` to the custom element `<input-debounce>` through an @Input property and assigning correctly to the property `aria-label` as described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute) (you don't have to initialize the value for the property you pass as @Input within the component though as it already gets a value assigned to it from the parent template).

```
// this declaration below
// @Input() ariaLabel = "";
// can be changed to
@Input() ariaLabel: string;
```

The same goes for other 2 @Input declarations as well as they already are getting values passed through input properties (attributes). You only have to specify its `type`, 'string' (or whatever it is), just like for `ariaLabel`. The @Input property's name for setting the `aria-label` (here, `ariaLabel`) doesn't matter as long as it is assigned rightly to the `aria-label` attribute within the component's template.

Generalizing, you can declare (any) custom input property name, say `customForAriaLabel` and pass it the value to be used within the component's template like this,

> parent template

```
<input-debounce
  [inputType]="'number'"
  [placeholder]="'Enter Number'"
  [customForAriaLabel]="'Age'">
</input-debounce>
```

> custom component with its template

```
var template = `
  <input
    [type]="inputType"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    [aria-label]="customForAriaLabel">
`;

@Component({
  selector: "input-debounce"
  template: template
})

export class InputDebounceComponent {
  @Input() inputType: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() customForAriaLabel: string;
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yup that makes sense! it's also the way I approached the problem (using the second way). But someone on the team with Angular experience suggested the first way which confused me since I'm still new to Angular. I just wanted to confirm my understanding: since it's a custom component you can't simply add an property binding to it, was correct and wasn't going crazy!